# pyside6-uic : The term 'pyside6-uic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet in windows 11 and VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, qt-designer, pyside6

[image: Error Message pyside6]

I am learning to create GUI interfaces using Qt designer and I am trying to convert my .ui file to a .py file. I have attempted to install pyside6 using pip3 install pyside6 - and pyside6 essentials in the power-shell on VSC. It still produces the same error.

I also installed QT for python as an extension on VSC but I am still unable to fix the issue of it not being recognised

I tried installing pyside through the powershell and the pyside essential package and that didnt fix it

I also installed Qt for python as stated above.

Comment: if you figured it out, you can actually answer your own question instead of including the supposed answer in your question. This might help others with similar issues.

Comment: Thankyou, I will! Still learning the best ways to use stack overflow

Comment: also remove the answer from the question since you've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I installed the anaconda navigator and prompt, installed pip3 pyside6 and then opened VSC in the anaconda nav and the conversion worked as intended.

https://www.anaconda.com/download - the anaconda navigator download if anyone needs it.

Comment: Hi Connor Davis, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Thankyou for all the help understanding StackOverflow and to help others! Just done that now